# Issue in using template in the view in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a question related to backbone.js and I need your help. I cannot understand the difference between:

```
currentCustomersTemplate : currentCustomersTemplate,
maincustomerTemplate : _.template(MainCustomerTemplate),
```

I mean the template with `_.` and the one that does not have it! Suppose I have a form (customer form) and inside this form I want to make (separate) forms related to each customer. So every time I add a customer by a button the information for each one goes to the `currentCustomer` form , which is "in" the main `customerForm`. (can be like multiple tables inside a bigger table). So I have two templates.  Whats the difference of the first and second?

Comment: Your `maincustomerTemplate` is using the underscore library. The `currentCustomersTemplate` is not. Without seeing more of the code, I don't know what else to tell you at this point.

Comment: `_.template();` is part of the (http://underscorejs.org/#template) library and returns a template function which can be utilized to render html.

I don't really understand exactly what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you want to make a new view for each customer-form you're adding.

Answer (score 1):

[_.template ()](http://underscorejs.org/#template) 'compiles' a raw template into a template object and you can provide different parameters for 'compiling'. You can read [underscore template doc in here](http://underscorejs.org/#template) for more details.

By following what you said, "currentCustomersTemplate" should have been already compiled before and it is a template object.  You should see in somewhere prior being referred and there must be _.template() being called already.